# Why iisn't my function working when it's called?

Tags: c++, windows

So i'm making a program that will simulate the keypress "a" and then hit enter using my enter key function, however the function just doesn't work. When I run the program it will hit the a key, but it just seems that the function hitDaEnterKey doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include <windows.h>



int hitDaEnterKey()
{
    INPUT ip;

    // Press and release Enter Key
    ip.ki.wVk = 0x0D;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    // release
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT)); 

    return 0;
}

int main()
{

    // This structure will be used to create the keyboard
    // input event.
    INPUT ip;


    Sleep(2500);

    // Set up a generic keyboard event.
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0; 

    // Press the "A" key

    ip.ki.wVk = 0x41; // virtual-key code for the "a" key
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    // Release the "A" key

    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT)); 

    hitDaEnterKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, the code is broken.

Comment: @SANICTHEHEDGEHOGOnonymus note that you're getting flippant/sarcastic comments because your question doesn't fulfil the quality standards of the site. Instead of calling other users "Sherlock", you might try [reading the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improving your question.

Comment: You are not specifying the input type in that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int hitDaEnterKey()
{
    INPUT ip;

    // Set up a generic keyboard event.
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    // Press and release Enter Key
    ip.ki.wVk = 0x0D;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    // release
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT)); 

    return 0;
}
```

**OR**

```
    int hitDaEnterKey(INPUT *ip)
    {        
        // Press and release Enter Key
        ip->ki.wVk = 0x0D;
        ip->ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, ip, sizeof(INPUT));
        // release
        ip->ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        SendInput(1, ip, sizeof(INPUT)); 

        return 0;
    }

int main()
{

    // This structure will be used to create the keyboard
    // input event.
    INPUT ip;


    Sleep(2500);

    // Set up a generic keyboard event.
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0; 

    // Press the "A" key

    ip.ki.wVk = 0x41; // virtual-key code for the "a" key
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    // Release the "A" key

    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT)); 

    hitDaEnterKey(&ip);

    return 0;
}
```